# Discover object type in tree

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative

I am effectively reproducing the viewer's model explorer primarily for Inventor type assemblies. I have retrieved the object tree using .net core api call to GetModelviewMetadataAsync.

My question is, how can I find out the object types for those objects in this tree. Specifically I want to know if an object is an:

1. Assembly
2. Part
3. Solid

I do not want to use the viewer to discover this, rather calls to the modelDerivative API

More detail.
Our application allows users to upload multiple files in a session (parts and assemblies typically). These files are not related, that is the parts may not belong to an assembly. We want to reproduce the functionality of the viewer's "Model browser" by displaying a tree to allow a user to browse a collection of files and explore parts in an assembly. I could not see how to do that in the viewer so we have created our own tree using calls to the model derivative to get each files object tree

[image]

This all works fine. What I would like to do to improve this, is to add an icon next to an object in the tree to represent the object type. Is it an assembly, part or solid?

@eason, see extra above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's unsupported by Model Derivative API

Comment: Thank you, Are there any options outside of the model derivative api?

Comment: Only with the viewer I'm afraid at this moment. Could you share your use case in detail? if your answer cannot be shared publicly, please reach out to `forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com` to create a support case. **Note. Please DON'T share confidential content.**

Comment: Hi Eason, I have updated the question to provide more detail. Please let me know it you need more.

Comment: Hi @Eason I have updated the question to provide more detail. Please let me know it you need more. –

Comment: Sorry for missing this. We're busying for Forge accelerator currently. Unfortunately, it's not supported, but you can try to check if this blog [Accessing design metadata without the Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/accessing-design-metadata-without-viewer) help. I'm not an expert with the Inventor. sorry~